# Display HTML form depending on employee title

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an update page where I check the title of the employee whether he is a doctor or a nurse. If the employee is a doctor/nurse an HTML form will be shown, if not a doctor/nurse, patient information will only be displayed and cannot be edited. But my code somehow skips  the part where I wanted to display the form even if I am logged in as a doctor/nurse. Can you please help me with this....

```
<?php
$a=$_SESSION['employeeID'];
$title="SELECT title FROM employee WHERE employeeID = '$a'";

if($title == 'nurse' OR $title == 'doctor')
{

echo '<form method="post" id="customForm" action="add_assessment.php">
<table>
<input type="hidden" name="res_id" value="' . $_GET['res_id'] . '" />
<tr>
<td><label for="name"><font style="color:white">Symptoms</font><font style="color:gray"></font></label>
<input id="name" name="symptoms" type="text" /></td>
<td><label for="name"><font style="color:white">Respiratory Rate</font></label>
<input id="name" name="respiratoryRate" type="text" /></td>
<td><label for="name"><font style="color:white">Temperature</font> <font     style="color:gray"></font></label>
<input id="name" name="temperature" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="name"><font style="color:white">Blood Pressure</font></label>
<input id="name" input name="bloodPressure" type="text" class="input2"/></td>
<td><label for="name"><font style="color:white">Pulse Rate</font></label>
<input id="name" input name="pulseRate" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="name"><font style="color:white">Chief Complaint</font></label>
<input id="name" input name="complaint" type="text" class="input2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>';
}
else 
{
$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password=""; // password
$db_name="rhu"; // Database name
$tbl_name="assessment"; // Table name 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");
$id = $_GET['res_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assessment WHERE patientID='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<p>ID: ".$id."</p>";
echo "<p>Assessment ID: ".$row['assessmentID']."</p>";
echo "<p>Symptoms: ".$row['symptoms']."</p>";
echo "<p>Respiratory Rate: ".$row['respiratoryRate']."</p>";
echo "<p>Temperature: ".$row['temperature']."</p>";
echo "<p>Blood Pressure: ".$row['bloodPressure']."</p>";
echo "<p>Pulse Rate: ".$row['pulseRate']."</p>";
echo "<p>Complaints: ".$row['complaint']."</p>";
echo "<p>Date: ".$row['date']."</p>";
echo "<br>";

}
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not executing the MySQL query

Comment: You should look into separating your presentation from your application logic. As your application gets larger and more complex, it is going to become more difficult to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this--

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM employee WHERE employeeID = '$a'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$title = $row['title'];

if($title == 'nurse' OR $title == 'doctor')
{
```

...continue you coding

Comment: A deprecated solution is not a good answer. the mysql_* extension will be phased out shortly and his code will stop working!

Answer (score 1):

In its current state, you are simply assigning a string to the variable `$title`. You are *literally* saying that `$title` is the string `"SELECT title FROM employee WHERE employeeID = '$a'";` therefore it is skipping the `if($title == 'nurse' OR $title == 'doctor')`.

You are also not executing a MySQL query, try this first

```
$a=$_SESSION['employeeID'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM employee WHERE employeeID = '"$a"'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $title = $row['title'];
if($title == 'nurse' OR $title == 'doctor')
{
   echo....
```

You should also note that `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be phased out of PHP as a solution in the future. To future-proof your code, consider using `mysqli` or PDO transactions.